# Array passing error in "A PHP Error was encountered" MySQL table

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to pass data ralated to master detail concept using php array to a MySQL table. Code of detail section is as follows :

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {
        $count = count($this->input->post('vote'));         
        $votes = $this->input->post('vote');
        $amount = $this->input->post('amount'); 
        $notes = $this->input->post('notes'); 
        
        for ($x = 0; $x < $count; $x++) {           
                $details[$x]['voucher_id'] = $id;
                $details[$x]['vote'] = $votes[$x];
                $details[$x]['amount'] = $amount[$x];              
                $details[$x]['notes'] = $notes[$x];             
                $details[$x]['status'] = 1; 
            }    
        }   
   if ($this->Voucher_model->updateVoteDetailsById($details)) {   
     $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Votes are added Successfully ..!!');   
        }
```

And the model is used as follows :

```
public function updateVoteDetailsById($details)
{
    $this->db2->insert_batch('tbl_voucher_votes', $details);
    if ($this->db2->affected_rows() == true) {
        foreach ($details as $array) {
        } 
        return true;
    }
}
```

The table named tbl_voucher_votes is including columns as voucher_vote_id, voucher_id, vote, amount, notes & status.

## Desired Result

The following output is expected.

```
+-----------------+------------+------+--------+-------+--------+
| voucher_vote_id | voucher_id | vote | amount | notes | status |
+-----------------+------------+------+--------+-------+--------+
|               1 |          2 |   16 |  14500 |       |      1 |
|               2 |          4 |   18 |  65900 |       |      1 |
|               3 |          3 |   12 |  26200 |       |      1 |
+-----------------+------------+------+--------+-------+--------+
```

## Error

When executing the code, the following error is occured.

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: details

Filename: controllers/Voucher.php

Line Number: 466

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\cssams\application\controllers\Voucher.php
Line: 466
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\cssams\index.php
Line: 269
Function: require_once

A Database Error Occurred
You must use the "set" method to update an entry.

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/cssams/application/models/Voucher_model.php

Line Number: 109
```

What may be going wrong ? Can anyone help me ?

Comment: You should really clarify which line of the code you have shown the error message is referring to, instead of having us guess.

Comment: I am guessing it is referring to this line, `if ($this->Voucher_model->updateVoteDetailsById($details))`? When `if ($this->form_validation->run() == true)` was not fulfilled, and you did not declare the variable anywhere before this - then it simply won't exist at the second if. The bad code indentation of course further obstructs that fact here.

Answer (score 3):

The error are saying what's going on. Always read error messages and try to think for at least 15 minutes.

The 1st error: `Message: Undefined variable: details`
It's because you're trying to use the `$details` variable before it's defined in the loop. So initialize it before the if condiition.

```
$details = array();
```

And in your model I would do:

```
 public function updateVoteDetailsById($details)
{
    $this->db2->insert_batch('tbl_voucher_votes', $details);
    if ($this->db2->affected_rows() > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

However I believe that the `You must use the "set" method to update an entry` error is occurring somewhere else that is not shown in your provided code.

Comment: When applying your suggestions to the code another error is outs as follows : A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given

Filename: database/DB_query_builder.php

Line Number: 1505

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\cssams\application\models\Voucher_model.php
Line: 109
Function: insert_batch

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\cssams\application\controllers\Voucher.php
Line: 469
Function: updateVoteDetailsById

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\cssams\index.php
Line: 269
Function: require_once